# Horizontally scrolling in not working in android

Tags: android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

In my following code horizontal scrolling is not working while displaying the data but vertically it's working properly. This java code is working properly if the data is in only one screen but if the data is out of screen, it hides, i'm not able to find out the problem. I used scrollview for scrolling, tablelayout and textview.  Please help me :

**(I didn't make any changes in xml file)**

```
private void Showdata()

{

    try {
        database = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE, null);

        int count = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());


        //added line from here
        ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
        scrollview.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        scrollview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        scrollview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        scrollview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        scrollview.addView(tl);
        //to here

        TableRow tr;
        TextView tv, tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5,tv6;

        tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tr.setId(200);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



        tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        tv.setText("Name");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        tr.addView(tv);

        tv4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv4.setText("Reg Id");
        tv4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tv4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        tr.addView(tv4);

        tv5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv5.setText("Mobile");
        tv5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tv5.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        tr.addView(tv5);

        tl.addView(tr);

        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++) {

            tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

            tv6 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv6.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            tv6.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            tv6.setText(c.getString(4));
            tr.addView(tv6);

            tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            // tv1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            // tv1.setText(c.getString(0));
            // tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            tv1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tv1.setText(c.getString(0));

            tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            // tv2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mobile")));
            tv2.setText(c.getString(1));
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);

            tv3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            // tv3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
            tv3.setText(c.getString(2));
            tv3.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);

            tv2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            tv3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            tr.addView(tv1);
            tr.addView(tv2);
            tr.addView(tv3);
            tl.addView(tr);
            c.moveToNext();

        }

        setContentView(scrollview);//modified line
        database.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception in showdata " + e,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of TableLayout. TableLayout has many issues with drawing and positioning.

Comment: Thanks Anitha for very quick reply. Let me check whether it works or not

Comment: Try this.. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/

Comment: @AnithaManikandan- no its not working. I changed LinearLayout at the place ot TableLayout but it's not working. Even not a single data shown while using LinearLayout. Please check it out again

Comment: Check the link I have mentioned.

Comment: Do you want the table to be scrolled or a single line horizontal scroll?

Comment: In above example they use xml coding for horizontal scrolling, but i want to do same dynamically(by using of java code). I didn't make any type of changes in xml code. @AnithaManikandan

Comment: Do you want the grid to be scrolled or a single row horizontal scroll?

Comment: I want full table data to be scrolled.@AnithaManikandan

Comment: anyhow I want to see my total data available in my SQLite database. Please help me out. @AnithaManikandan

Comment: horizontal scrollview and vertically scrollview creates complications when used simulatenously...genereally vertical scrollview supress horizontal scrollview due to which horizontal scrollview dsnt work..for vertical scrolling u can use listview instead

Comment: @Neha thanks , but in listview data not shown properly that the main problem.

Comment: y not properly..u can set the data the way u want in listview..how do u want the data to be shown??

Comment: I want my data like a tabular form. under **name** column only name, under **Email** only email. Data should not be mismatch. is it possible @Neha

Comment: Can you please suggest for listview where i've to make changes in my code???

Comment: yes it is possible... u can user listview with headers

Comment: I din't get you. would you like to explain please???

Comment: ok lets do one thing...create a listview and its item layout..in item layout put the tablelayout and inflate it in listview...itz a bit tricky but will solve your problem

Comment: can you please give me any sample code for that, I'm fully unaware about it :(

Comment: u can take example from this code http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92.

Comment: if still u r clueless.feel free to ask

Comment: @Neha - Thanks a lot. If yu've time please check my code once that would be more helpful for me.

Comment: so your code working???

Comment: @Neha- yeah my code is working properly but only for vertical scrolling